# Google in-app not able to find the product

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app

I'm trying to implement in-app product purchase in my app so I followed all the steps shown in tutorial to do that it was working fine but when I added actual product in in-app purchase and tried doing that I was getting "Error: Authentcation is required. you need to sign into your google account"..when I googled for this problems I found few solutions but when I applied them it is not working in my case...

### ERROR

[image]

### Purchase Function

```
public void purchase ()
{
    ArrayList skuList = new ArrayList();
    skuList.add(inappid);
    Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
    querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);
    Bundle skuDetails;
    try {
        skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3, getPackageName(),
                "inapp", querySkus);

        int response = skuDetails.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
        if (response == 0) {

            Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService
                    .getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), "snooze",
                            "inapp",
                            "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle
                    .getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
            startIntentSenderForResult(
                    pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 10001,
                    new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0),
                    Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));
        }
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

### Console

[image]

Comment: have you installed signed apk ? if not then install signed apk in your device .

Comment: have you setup google account to your device on which you are testing? check [this](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-test) too.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, how are you testing the IAP (In-app Purchase)?

Then let us know whether you signed your APK before you test?

Next, if after you signed your APK, you need to upload to Playstore as Alpha version (and wait 1 to few hours to process). Remember to set your google email (that you login on your phone) as closed alpha (& beta) tester.

Finally download your app from Playstore and try again.